# Rails Ajax - View Filtering by joined record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to allow an end user to filter a data grid by an associated record. The data grid is showing a list of Activities:

Model for **activity.rb** (the list of records)

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Model for **student.rb** (what I'm trying to filter on)

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :activities
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], :convert_options => "-auto-orient"
    validates :firstname, :presence => true

end
```

Here's the view in **index.html.erb**:

```
<heading>

    <h1 class="activity">Activity</h1> 

    <div class="filter">
        <%= collection_select :students, :ids, Student.where(user_id: current_user), :id, :firstname, {}, {:onchange => '$.get("/filter_students")'} %>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <div class="timeblock">
            <div class="label">Date</div>
            <div class="value"><%= activity.created_at.strftime("%b %e") %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="student-name"><%= activity.student.try{|s| s.firstname} || "Deleted Student" %></div>
        <%= activity.name %>
    </div>

...
```

and my **activities_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @activities = Activity.where(user_id: current_user).order('created_at DESC').limit(50)
end
def filter_students
    @activities = Activity.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'student_activites', :formats => [:js] }
    end
end
```

I'm getting the select with the students first names back, but when I click it, here's the js error I'm getting:

> GET http://localhost:3000/filter_students 404 (Not Found)

*Edit* Here's the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :activities
  resources :students
end
```

Comment: Can you add the route you're using to the question?

Comment: Where's the route for `/filter_students`? Right now you only have two entries in your routes file and neither are configured to respond to a `GET` request at `/filter_students`

Answer (score 0):

The URL the app is retrieving is: http://localhost:3000/filter_students. You need to change to something like this: http://localhost:3000/activities/filter_students, to specify the controller of your action. Just add the controller to your `onchange` directive on the `collection_select`.
You also need to tell `Rails` that you have a route `filter_students` inside your `ActivitiesController` that is applied to a `collection`, e.g the filter student is not applied to a specific `activity`, so you need to put in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :activities do
  collection do
    get :filter_students
  end
end
resources :students
```

Comment: Now getting `GET http://localhost:3000/activities/filter_students 404 (Not Found)`. I've even added that as a view with the markup from index

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the filter_students route:

```
get 'filter_students', to: 'activities#filter_student'
```

Comment: The call is still 404 and when I hit that page manually, I get `Couldn't find Activity with 'id'=filtered_students` in `@activity = Activity.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current construction of your `filter_students` method in your **activities_controller** I would do this:

**routes.rb**

```
# filter_students is trying to find @activities based on params[:id]
## so you need to send params[:id] via the member do block of the activites resource below
resources :activities do
  # member rather than collection
  # member will allow you to pass params[:id] like you have in you controller
  member do
    get :filter_students
  end
end
resources :students
```

Then use `activity.id` (it looks like you are already using `activity` in your index view) to the activity id to the url

**index.html.erb - edited 1/3/17**

```
<%# your onchange url needs to look like this /activity/:id/filter_students %>
<%# ... to work with the routes you setup above and the logic in your controller %>
<%= collection_select :students, :ids, Student.where(user_id: current_user), :id, :firstname, {}, {:onchange => '$.get("/activity/<%= activity.id %>/filter_students")'} %>
```

Comment: I'm getting `jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:10255 GET http://localhost:3000/filter_students 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Window.location.href should be slipping 'activity/:id/' in that URL

Comment: This is what it's showing in the DOM `onchange="$.get("http://localhost:3000/filter_students")"`

Comment: Can you add your activity id to a data attribute on that button on the view? Then it would be accessible as a JavaScript variable to be used in your on change URL

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry just now looking back at this... you need to get your onchange url into this format: `onchange="$.get("http://localhost:3000/activity/:id/filter_students")"` so I made an adjustment to `<%= collection_select ... %>` to try to pass the activity id into the url